# Search Text Box jumping while navigating to other pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I do not really know, when this problem occurred.
When you open http://bmsc.tfei.info/en/ -Search-box location is fine,
when you navigate to any page http://bmsc.tfei.info/en/about-us it jumps to upper.
What can cause such a problem?
In all browsers the same problem.
What I did is separated 2 stylesheet one for english version and one for russian version;
And added jQuery library.
Please help, thanks in advance!

Here is my css for div search

```
#search
{
width:28%;
margin:0;
float:right;
height:40px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
}
```

and textbox with button

```
#mod-search-searchword { 
border-radius: 3px;
margin-top: 3px;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 0px;
width:72%;
min-width:150px;
height:10px;
}
.search .button{
margin-top:3px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:3px;
}
```

and html code

```
       <div id='search' >        
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="well" />
</div>
```

Comment: paste your code for both of your pages

Comment: What kind of code do you need? CSS, HTML?

Comment: i would suggest you that remove that `style="well"` and change it to `class="well"` if you are using bootstrap!

Comment: I am using bootsrapper but it is Joomla feature style="well" It did not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here...

```
#top {
overflow: visible !important;
}
```

This rule is not being used on the other pages.